# SimpleXML: Add XML attribute values to an array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, simplexml

I want to create an array from the `id` attributes of the element `<b>`, however the below code returns all XML.

**PHP file:**

```
$xmlfile=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$test=$xmlfile->xpath("/a//b[@id]");
```

**XML file(fixed):**

```
<a>
  <b id="1"></b>
  <b id="2"></b>
  <b id="3"></b>
  <b id="4"></b>
  <b id="5"></b>
</a>
```

Comment: How looks exactly your xml file? Are attribute values enclosed between quotes?

Comment: I corrected the XML sample and improved the formatting, spelling, the title and the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello_ mate

If I understood you right this code snippet will do the job:

**SOLUTION 1**

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$items = $xmlfile->xpath("/a//b[@id]");

$result = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $result[] = $item['id']->__toString();
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
exit;

// Output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
$sampleHtml = file_get_contents("test.xml");

$result = array();
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if ($dom->loadHTML($sampleHtml)) {
    $bElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
    foreach ($bElements as $b) {
        $result[] = $b->getAttribute('id');
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
exit;

// Output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract just `id` attribute values from `<b>` tags, try below `XPath`:

```
/a/b/@id
```

as `/a//b[@id]` means extracting all `b` elements that have `id` attribute and that are descendants of `a`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like both existing answers tell you half of what you need to know.

Firstly, your XPath is subtly wrong: `b[@id]` means "any b element which has an attribute id". You want instead `b/@id`, meaning "any id attribute which is a child of a b element".

Secondly, the SimpleXML `xpath` method returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects representing the elements or attributes matched. To get just the text contents of those attributes, you need to cast each one to string, using `(string)$foo`.

So:

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$test = $xmlfile->xpath("/a//b/@id");
$list = [];
foreach ( $test as $attr ) {
    $list[] = (string)$attr;
}
```

[[Live Demo]](https://3v4l.org/T2vNr)